# SQL Select taking too much time on table with 25M record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to select from `LogTable` with 25,000,000 rows records within a date range

```
    SET STATISTICS TIME ON 
    SET STATISTICS IO ON

    SELECT LogId, LogDate FROM LogTable 
    WHERE LogDate >= '10/4/2017 12:00:00 AM' and LogDate < '10/4/2018 9:32:29 AM'


    SQL Server parse and compile time: 
       CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

    (5258811 row(s) affected)
    Table 'LogTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 16974, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 
     SQL Server Execution Times:
       CPU time = 2125 ms,  elapsed time = 30464 ms.
```

What are the options to improve performance in MS SQL 2014? I read about table partition but I am not sure if that will help.

Comment: You have a proper index on the field? If not - get mor eram and get faster SSD is the only answer. Partitioning is NOT more efficient for selects - it is a database management tool (i.e. super fast deletes).

Comment: Also, you select 5258811  rows - unless you count only, I hope you run 100g networks if you want fast data transfers.

Comment: What is the table definition, including any indexes?  Also, you should turn on IO statistics as well and let us know what they are.

Comment: How long is "too long"?

Comment: @rbarryyoung I updated the code with IO statistics

Comment: Slight detour....you should get in the habit of using the ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD format for dates.

Comment: FWIW, if you can add enough RAM that there's no disk activity required by the queries, it will run faster. Also, if you can do it, using a single-byte character set will improve performance over multi-byte.

Comment: 30s for 5M out of 25M does not sound like "too much".

Comment: @TerryCarmen It's doing 0 physical reads on +16k logical reads, so it's already doing everything from cache.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting 5M rows out of 25M: that is, you are selecting 20% of the table.

Typical indexes won't really work with such a high percentage.

However, you can still use a "covering index" that *could* make it faster. Try and see:

```
create index ix1 on LogTable (LogDate, LogId);
```

Comment: Why did you use LogId into your index ?, i think that it is better to just add LogDate , because you are using it on your where clause

Comment: The covering index didnt help

Comment: @AlvaroParra Adding `LogId` makes this index a "covering index". SQL Server can use this secondary index by itself without the need to access the primary index.

Comment: did you try to update your statistics @Jefferson EXEC sp_updatestats;

Comment: @AlvaroParra Yes statistics are all up to date